# php array combine values until string limit reached

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with string with certain lenght of characters:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => hello
    [3] => world
    [4] => i
    [5] => great
)
```

I need to combine those values into chunks until some string length limit is reached.

**For example max char number is 6**

So new array would look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => foobar
    [1] =>  hello
    [2] => worldi
    [3] => great
)
```

"Foo" and "Bar", "i" and "world" merges, because it does not exceed 6 max allowed char limit.
However "Hello" don't because combined char limit exceeds 6.

Can't wrap my head around how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy:

```
$arr = array('foo','bar','hello', 'world', 'i', 'great');
$limit = 6;
$result = array(''); // some hack
$cur_key = 0;        // some hack
foreach ($arr as $word) {
    if (strlen($result[$cur_key]) + strlen($word) <= $limit) {
        $result[$cur_key] .= $word;
    } else {
        $result[] = $word;
        $cur_key++;
    }
}
```

Comment: array functions exist for a reason.

Comment: What array function? For what reason?

Comment: you are doing it manually using a foreach, strlen and an if. implode and str_split are your friends.

Comment: Your function even doesn't do what OP wants.

Comment: it's not "my" function. it's php's. and you should try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:

```
// YOUR ARRAY
$array = array('foo', 'bar', 'hello', 'world', 'i', 'great');

// STRING CONTAINING YOUR ARRAY VALUES CONCATENATED
$alltogheter = implode("", $array);

// NEW ARRAY FROM YOUR STRING (SPLIT BY 6 CHARS)
$newarray = str_split($alltogheter, 6);
```

Comment: Result of your function: `array(4) { [0]=> string(6) "foobar" [1]=> string(6) "hellow" [2]=> string(6) "orldig" [3]=> string(4) "reat" } `

Comment: exactly. I don't see any whitespaces in OP's array.

Comment: OP wants `[1] =>  hello [2] => worldi` You give him: `[1]=> string(6) "hellow" [2]=> string(6) "orldig"`.

Comment: Do you even understand that your code return results that's not like OP wants?

Comment: yes I can read: **I need to combine those values into chunks until some string length limit is reached. For example max char number is 6**

Comment: @u_mulder did you read the question or did you just took under consideration his output example?

Comment: I considered his output example. That's all.

Comment: @u_mulder way around is better because it does not combine values if combined they would exceed max number. <pre>Array
(
    [0] =&gt; foobar
    [1] =&gt; hello
    [2] =&gt; worldi
    [3] =&gt; great
    [4] =&gt; greats
    [5] =&gt; i
)
</pre>
GrafiCode Studio  str_split() function does not care it combines everything